# How to pass data from CloudWatch event rule to Lambda?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I have created a Lambda in CDK Package. I want to create a CloudWatch EventBridge Rule that triggers a Lambda. I want to pass my values to the Lambda using the CloudWatch Rule itself.
I don't want to make any changes to the CDK code. How can I do it? What are the possible options?

Can I use Tags or Events?

Comment: If you created the rule using CDK, then you have to use CDK to add the event that you want to pass to your Lambda. Or, if the values are already known, just add it inside the Lambda itself.

Comment: not creating the rule using CDK.

Comment: The values are variable, based on the values received, we create the cloudwatch rule.

Comment: You can then use your Lambda to create the rule with the corresponding event.

Comment: I can't directly use the Lambda, I need to pass some values to the Lambda function from the CloudWatch Rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data from Cloudwatch Rule to the lambda that it triggers by passing a JSON as Input. Pass the Input JSON to the Target.

Example:

```
final Target target = new Target()
                .withId(LAMBDA_TARGET_ID)
                .withArn(functionArn)
                .withInput(jsonString);
```